# PhantomJS seems to stop responding after a few interactions in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm running a web scraper using python 2.7 with selenium 2.52 and PhantomJS 2.1.1 and PhantomJS seems to time out at some point and become unresponsive.  I can't find any rhyme or reason to when or why it quits, but after a certain amount of time, any get() requests don't throw exceptions, but will not load a new page.  Calling current_url() will always show the last loaded page and will never change unless I close the current instance and start a new one.  I can't get screenshots or source code because I get a connection refused error.

This is not the code I use, but a simplified version that duplicates the issue I'm having that just loads box scores from ESPN.  Sometimes the following code will run for 30 seconds before Phantom craps out, other times it will run for several minutes.  Every time however, I can close the instance and restart a new one and it'll run.  Perhaps there are some debugging tools I don't know about that can help get to the root cause of this?  I run the same code using Chrome instead of PhantomJS and it'll run forever.

```
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='$HOME/env/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(2000,2000)
start_time = time.time()
def url_test(first_id, last_id):
    for id in range(first_id, last_id):
        url = "http://espn.go.com/nba/boxscore?gameId=" + str(id)
        print(driver.current_url)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(driver.current_url)
        if driver.current_url != url:
            print('URL failed to load: ' + url + ' at ' + str(time.time() - start_time) + ' elapsed seconds')
            driver.close()
            sys.exit()

url_test(400828768, 400828968)
```

Comment: By default phantomjs logs to file `ghostdriver.log`.
Have you checked the content of this log?